# Increment a char pointer in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, while-loop, increment

I am working on a question from Cracking the Coding Interview. The question is: Write code to reverse a C-Style String. 
And here is the answer I got that is written in c++, but I don't understand the meaning behind increment a char pointer.

```
void swap(char &a, char &b){
    a = a^b;
    b = a^b;
    a = a^b;
}

void reverse1(char *s){
    if(!s) return;
    char *p = s, *q = s;
    while(*q) ++q;
    --q;
    while(p < q)
        swap(*p++, *q--);
}
```

The part that I don't understand is in the second function from the first while loop. What is the condition `*p`? And why increment `q` will chop off the starting character in the string?

For example, if

```
char s[] = "1234567890";
```

After you pass `s` into function `reverse1`, why will `++q` give you a result like `"234567890"`?

Comment: please don't use xor `^` for swapping, it's broken, use a temporary variable.

Comment: C strings are null terminated, so the `while(*q)` loop goes over the characters in the string until it encounters the null character (which evaluates to 0 / false).

Comment: Step 1. **First, please learn the basics of C.** Step 2. Try answering the questions yourself. 3. **ONLY** if you're still stuck, come back and ask a question. This really is too basic.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows the lack of fundamental knowledge of the language being used and lack of research about the problem itself.

Comment: Do not use xor swapping, it's slower than using a temporary on most modern systems, and prone to aliasing https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm#Reasons_for_avoidance_in_practice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`p` and `q` are pointer to `char` and both are initialized as the address of the first `char` in the `string s[]` (as the name of an array in `C` is a pointer to its first element). `while (*q) q++;` increases  `q` (the position of `char`) until it reaches the end of the string ( `NULL` character `'\0'`). and `--q` decreases the position to point to one before `NULL` char which is the last element (char) of the string.

That is why after passing an string to `reverse1()` and doing `++q`, the result would start from the second char rather than the first one.

Answer (score 2):

Strings are arrays. q is pointing to the first character of the string. So when you increase q. q will point to the next character.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

C style strings are null(0x00 or /0) terminated.

`char s[] = "1234567890";` will be stored in memory like this: 
`0x31 0x32 0x33 0x34 0x35 0x36 0x37 0x38 0x39 0x30 0x00`

The first while loop is searching for end of string.

At start of while loop `q` points to `0x31`.

In each iteration q is incremented to point to next memory location.

When `q` points to `0x00` loop breaks.

Answer (score -1):

Thats the question for '`\0'` which terminates the string.

and the result is:

```
0987654321
```

as expected from a function called reverse (in `Visual Studio 2013`)